# Left join execute like right join [how to find the cause?]

Tags: postgresql

I have simple query

```
explain  SELECT * FROM markets LEFT JOIN outcomes ON markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid WHERE markets.event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0';
```

and explain show me

```
Merge Right Join  (cost=63274.17..905696.60 rows=78271 width=8201)
  Merge Cond: (outcomes.market_uuid = markets.uuid)
  ->  Index Scan using outcomes_market_uuid_index on outcomes  (cost=0.43..802379.27 rows=15654269 width=2776)
  ->  Sort  (cost=63273.73..63336.34 rows=25043 width=5425)
        Sort Key: markets.uuid
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on markets  (cost=220.92..27250.08 rows=25043 width=5425)
              Recheck Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on markets_event_uuid_index  (cost=0.00..214.66 rows=25043 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
JIT:
  Functions: 9
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS)  SELECT * FROM markets 
LEFT JOIN outcomes ON markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid  
WHERE markets.event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0';
```

```
Merge Right Join  (cost=63274.17..905696.60 rows=78271 width=8201) (actual time=21215.656..21215.665 rows=2 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (outcomes.market_uuid = markets.uuid)
  Buffers: shared hit=7635492 read=600026 written=2031
  ->  Index Scan using outcomes_market_uuid_index on outcomes  (cost=0.43..802379.27 rows=15654269 width=2776) (actual time=0.111..19456.586 rows=8421452 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=7635488 read=600026 written=2031
  ->  Sort  (cost=63273.73..63336.34 rows=25043 width=5425) (actual time=0.047..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: markets.uuid
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on markets  (cost=220.92..27250.08 rows=25043 width=5425) (actual time=0.025..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              Buffers: shared hit=4
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on markets_event_uuid_index  (cost=0.00..214.66 rows=25043 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.416 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 9
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.989 ms, Inlining 4.691 ms, Optimization 200.586 ms, Emission 117.924 ms, Total 326.192 ms
Execution Time: 21218.828 ms
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM markets 
LEFT JOIN outcomes ON markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid 
WHERE markets.event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0';
```

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=98.69..681948.87 rows=269 width=4521) (actual time=31871.835..31871.846 rows=2 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (outcomes.market_uuid = markets.uuid)
  ->  Seq Scan on outcomes  (cost=0.00..640757.69 rows=15654269 width=2776) (actual time=0.034..29402.201 rows=15654279 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=97.62..97.62 rows=86 width=1745) (actual time=364.287..364.290 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
        ->  Index Scan using markets_event_uuid_index on markets  (cost=0.43..97.62 rows=86 width=1745) (actual time=0.027..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
Planning Time: 0.326 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 12
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 3.773 ms, Inlining 3.798 ms, Optimization 226.614 ms, Emission 133.456 ms, Total 367.641 ms
Execution Time: 31875.826 ms
```

Some information:

- The database has been restored from a backup
- Postgres has been restarted on the server
- Another query with Left Join working perfect
- Just this query above, join + where causes the problem
- Query time 20-30 s, on right join table with 15 million records
- Table has primary_key and index
- Version Postgres 15.2
- On local base (Version Postgres 14.3) works perfect

Query mixed where/join with time 1-5 ms (works perfect)

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS)  SELECT * FROM markets 
LEFT JOIN events ON markets.event_uuid = events.uuid 
WHERE markets.event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0';
```

```
Buffers: shared hit=8
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on markets  (cost=220.92..27250.08 rows=25043 width=5425) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
        Heap Blocks: exact=1
        Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on markets_event_uuid_index  (cost=0.00..214.66 rows=25043 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..2.65 rows=1 width=5491) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Index Scan using events_pkey on events  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=5491) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
              Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning Time: 0.384 ms
Execution Time: 0.253 ms
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS)  SELECT * FROM markets 
LEFT OUTER JOIN outcomes ON markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid 
WHERE markets.uuid = '6dc00c42-9b80-43a5-a263-5010648a38fd';
```

```
 Buffers: shared hit=3 read=6
  ->  Index Scan using markets_pkey on markets  (cost=0.43..2.65 rows=1 width=5425) (actual time=3.183..3.185 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (uuid = '6dc00c42-9b80-43a5-a263-5010648a38fd'::uuid)
        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on outcomes  (cost=781.94..78619.53 rows=78271 width=2776) (actual time=1.713..1.723 rows=2 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (market_uuid = '6dc00c42-9b80-43a5-a263-5010648a38fd'::uuid)
        Heap Blocks: exact=2
        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on outcomes_market_uuid_index  (cost=0.00..762.37 rows=78271 width=0) (actual time=1.682..1.682 rows=2 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (market_uuid = '6dc00c42-9b80-43a5-a263-5010648a38fd'::uuid)
              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
Planning Time: 0.360 ms
Execution Time: 4.975 ms
```

Why engine Postgres change my query? Cache? Bug? Can you help me?

Comment: Please share the whole query plan and also the structure of your table(s) with indexes. also, use `EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: I add more explain, i can't add structure of table(s), is against my agreement

Comment: I see. What kind of index are you using in `markets.uuid` and `outcomes.market_uuid`?

Comment: `read=600026` indicates that a lot of blocks couldn't be found in the buffer cache and therefore needed to be read from the disk or OS cache. Maybe your instances have different configurations?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX markets_event_uuid_index ON public.markets USING btree (event_uuid)`
`CREATE INDEX outcomes_market_uuid_index ON public.outcomes USING btree (market_uuid)`
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX outcomes_pkey ON public.outcomes USING btree (uuid)`
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX markets_pkey ON public.markets USING btree (uuid)`

Comment: for equality it's a good idea to use `hash indexes`: ["Hash indexes are best optimized for SELECT and UPDATE-heavy workloads that use equality scans on larger tables."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hash-intro.html)

Comment: I try check this lost rows, optimization is cool but that's not the cause of the problem

Comment: You mean the `read=600026` isn't the cause of the problem? Does it pop up in the 14 instance?

Comment: Also, make sure the table statistics are up to date, see `ANALYZE`

Comment: read=600026 I'm still checking, 
`optimization  isn't the cause of the problem`

Comment: Please add the results of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the queries you say run perfectly: it's impossible to identify differences with only one case. As @JimJones suggested, run `ANALYZE` on the restored DB. The restore method wasn't specified, but note that statistics aren't restored by `pg_restore`.

Comment: Someone else was handling the restore of the base. I add explain to good query and add ANALYZE  to bad query.

Comment: The slow and fast queries joining outcomes and markets are for different uuid values. The row counts for the different uuid values is significantly different, so comparing the plans is useless.

Comment: The execution plans for the latter query are not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Downgrade postgres to 14.8 fix the problem.** Thank you for your help. Thanks to you I understood a bit better how the database works and I learned new ways to analyze queries.

```
SELECT * FROM markets
LEFT JOIN outcomes ON markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid
WHERE markets.event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0';
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.87..2121.97 rows=441 width=2467) (actual time=0.050..0.053 rows=2 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=8
   ->  Index Scan using markets_event_uuid_index on markets  (cost=0.43..159.01 rows=141 width=2245) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (event_uuid = 'f286f78b-9e9c-4052-9785-7c908a8ab2c0'::uuid)
         Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Index Scan using outcomes_market_uuid_index on outcomes  (cost=0.43..13.81 rows=11 width=222) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=2 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (market_uuid = markets.uuid)
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=16
 Planning Time: 0.440 ms
 Execution Time: 0.124 ms
(12 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a query language not a programming language. The difference is that in programming language you write the exact code that the computer must execute, and in a query langage yous just specify what you want to have in the result set, not how !

So the optimizer, like Madame Mary Watson (Sherlock Holms landlady) must accomplish the task of answering your request in the smartest way, and that's why he rewrote your request, which is a mathematical equivalent sctict in order to answer you faster...

Comment: I understand, then how to tell him that he is wrong and make a left join out of it, is it a matter of some configuration / parameter?

Comment: The explain plan isn't wrong: `LEFT JOIN` with condition `markets.uuid = outcomes.market_uuid` is equivalent to `RIGHT JOIN` with condition ` outcomes.market_uuid = markets.uuid`. The optimizer/planner doesn't work directly with the query text, but instead with an abstract but semantically equivalent version. This is not a bug.